# Static Images Not Loading to CDN

Tags: magento-1.9, cdn

According to GTmetrix, I have 18 static images on the homepage that are not loading via the CDN. I cannot figure out why. I've posted a screenshot of GTMetrix and the Magento backend. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Because your image-urls are hardcoded in css:

[image]

To fix this problem, do the following:

1. disable css-merging from backend (`System` -> `Configuration` -> `ADVANCED` -> `Developer` then `CSS Settings` and set `Merge CSS Files` to `No`)
2. reload your frontend and view your page with developer tools (i.e. F12 in Google Chrome) and find the images mentioned in GTMetrix. (Probably they are all in the same styles.css file located in your skin folder)
3. Once you got the path to the CSS file(s), modify it so the path is "relative" (i.e. for you probably something like

---

```
.red-bar { background:url('../images/red_rptbg.jpg') ... }
/* ".." - these two dots will tell the browser that the image is located one directory below the current one (current = folder where your css file is located); "/images/" again tells the browser to access this folder on the webserver and then there's just your image' name left */
```

---

rather than

---

```
.red-bar { background:url('http://www.domian.com/skin/frontend/abc/xyz/images/red_rptbg.jpg') ... }`)
```

---

4. NOTE: as you're working with a CDN it might be necessary to purge the cache there after you've modified your css file (also note, the changes mentioned above are meant to be done on your webserver, not in the CDN, as the CDN will just fetch the files (usually on demand, i.e. on first access of a user for a particular source) from the webserver)

Comment: good man, can you tell me fix? sorry I am not proficient coder.

Comment: @st789 - see the update in the answer above

Comment: So something interesting happened. After I unmerged the CSS files (step #1), I was able to go into the specific CSS file for that page and the images were in fact given a relative path. here's a screenshot (https://i.imgur.com/7k2LWJ2.png). I then ran another gtmetrix test on the page (with the CSS unmerged), it is no longer showing the images as being left out of the CDN, but it is now showing CSS files being left out of the CDN. here's a screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/QxDqX).  Google Dev Tools also shows the image link properly to the CDN (https://i.imgur.com/3oPWO4Z.jpg). Confused...

Comment: @st789 Take a look at the paths, most of them start with "domain.com/js/..." - and your js-path is not in the CDN as per your configuration (https://i.imgur.com/nGuH0QY.png - see Base JavaScript URL). If you want these resources to be delivered by CDN, you need to set the CDN path there as well.

Comment: I see. Any idea why just unmerging the CSS files corrected the original issue with the images? Ideally I'd like to leave the Magento CSS Merge feature on.

Comment: @st789 - I think you're in some sort of caching conflict with your CDN. I'm not exactly sure under what specific condition the problem you're experiencing would occur as it did not happen to me so far, but I would assume you have merged your CSS before setting up CDN and this merged file (holding the real domain name at this point) then was pushed to CDN? So I guess it should be working if you're merging your CSS now, and get the new file pushed to CDN, else you may need to clear the merged CSS/JS files cache (System -> Cache Management). Apart from that, got any additional minifier installed?

Comment: prior to setting up the CDN, auto-merge for JS/CSS was turned on. the only other minifier we have running is pagespeed module for nginx, which is only a JS minifier.

Comment: @st789 - what's the outcome if your merge your CSS now again?

Comment: Hey man I ended up starting from scratch and setting up the CDN again and it ended up solving the problem. I must have done something wrong on setup last time. The only problem I'm having now is the CDN is blocking iframes on the site.

Comment: @st789, great you go it working. About the iframes however there will be more information required and I don't think that should be handled in the comments section any further as it probably is a different topic and not related to the initial troubles. I'd suggest to create a new question with more details on that topic.